# How to set multiple colors in one series in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can we set multiple color for a series in highchart's columnrange chart based on value. For e.g. if a series is starting it should have green and if its ending after a threshold limit color should be in red in same series.
[sample columnrange chart](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcLeeyz/)

I was trying below code to change the color but its not setting the different color from bottom to top: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEBjE/731/)

```
{
        linearGradient: merge(perShapeGradient),
        stops: [
        [0, 'green'],
        [1, 'red']
    ]
}
```

can anybody pls help me.

Comment: The gradient is on the x axis because you have the perShapeGradient set up that way. Here is a working example where I changed it from `x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0` to `x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1` http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/GEBjE/732/

Comment: Thank you @ewolden, it helped me move to next step. I want to achieve something like  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcLeeyz/6/) the color of bar should change if it crosses a value.

Answer (score 0):

Coloring by using gradient is rather hard task to do in this case.

**Workaround:**

You can split the point if it crosses the value that defines a color change:

```
{
    var series = this.series[0],
      points = series.points,
      newPoints = [];

    points.forEach((point) => {

      // add x value to options
      point.options.x = point.x;

      if (point.low < yThreshold && point.high > yThreshold) {
        // split the point
        newPoints.push($.extend({}, point.options, {
          low: point.low,
          high: yThreshold
        }), $.extend({}, point.options, {
          low: yThreshold,
          high: point.high
        }));

      } else {
        newPoints.push(point.options);
      }
    });

    // color the points
    newPoints.forEach(function(pointOptions) {
      if (pointOptions.high <= yThreshold) {
        pointOptions.color = '#C0FFEE';
      } else {
        pointOptions.color = '#BADA55';
      }
    });

    series.setData(newPoints);

  }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jfguhget/

Comment: thanks for your reply. Its changing the color after a threshold after splitting the data series. However problem is, its also splitting the dataLables and tooltip information into two points for e.g. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcLeeyz/18/). I dont want to split the data information on tooltip and labels. Can you please help.

Comment: Thanks Kamil Kulig it worked for me. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcLeeyz/30/) is the final output what I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Kamil Kulig, Is there any problem with events.load method in angular4. I have copied the same [code](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcLeeyz/32/) in angular 4 but its not working. I check and observed the load function inside event is not firing. Can u pls help.

Comment: Could you provide a live demo of this problem?